# Ratio between expectation of maximum of $n$ and $n-1$ IID random variables

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, conditional-independence

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid random variables. Define $Z_n = \max(X_1, ..., X_n)$. Can we lower bound
$$\mathbb{E}[Z_{n-1}] \geq (1-f(n))\mathbb{E}[Z_n]$$

Using some $f(n)$. I am mainly interested in small $n$.

Comment: @jbowman But $f(n)>0$ here? $\mathbb{E}[Z_n] \geq \mathbb{E}[Z_{n-1}]$ doesn't rule out $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n-1}] \geq (1-f(n))\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]$ for $f(n)>0$

Comment: Because you make no assumptions about the distribution, evidently you seek bounds in terms of some property or properties of the distribution.  What do you have in mind?

Comment: @whuber I was hoping for a general bound regardless what the distribution is. Here is one example of a loose bound: Let $F(t)=Pr[X_i \leq t]$. Then $Pr[Z_n>t]=1-F(t)^n$. But then $Pr[Z_{n-1}>t] = (1-F(t)^n) \frac{1-F(t)^{n-1}}{1-F(t)^n} \geq \frac{n-1}{n}(1-F(t)^n) = \frac{n-1}{n}Pr[Z_n>t]$, which implies $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n-1}]\geq (1-\frac{1}{n}) \mathbb{E}[Z_n]$

Comment: I was going to respond but realize I am confused by how you pose this question, because inequalities are not numbers and bounds make no sense for them.  What is it you want a lower bound for: $f(n),$ $1-f(n),$ or something else? Are you assuming the common distribution has positive support or not?

Comment: @whuber Yes, you can assume positive support. I am trying to *improve* the lower bound on $1-f(n)$, which as I showed above is at least $1-\frac{1}{n}$. For example, something interesting would be $1-f(n) \geq 1-\frac{1}{n^2}$ or something similar getting $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n-1}]$ closer to $\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]$ faster as $n$ increases.

Comment: Your lower bound is the best you can possibly do, because it is approached arbitrarily closely by any Bernoulli$(1-p)$ variable for sufficiently small $p.$